# document.getElementsByTagName('select') - select only from particular form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to select drop-downs and check them, so I'm using this code to do so -  `document.getElementsByTagName('select');` but the problem I'm facing is that I've got several forms on one page and I want to choose only drop-downs from form called `myform3` for example!

I found one example it looks like this - `myform3.document.getElementsByTagName('select');`  **but it only works in IE**

Could you tell me how to do that in every browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
document.forms['myform3'].getElementsByTagName('select')
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
document.myForm3.getElementsByTagName('select');
```

Not

```
myForm3.document.getElementsByTagName('select');
```

[Works in other browsers too.](http://jsfiddle.net/zpq46/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine..

```
   document.forms["form_name"].getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found one example it looks like this - `myform3.document.getElementsByTagName('select');` but it only works in IE

`myform3.getElementsByTagName` would be correct – `document`is out of place there.

(You can call `getElementsByTagName` on every node object to only get nodes that are descendants of it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
document.forms["myform3"].getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ID attribute of the form to myform3. Then you can do this:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("myform3");
var selects = myForm.getElementsByTagName("select");
```